# How to replace '?' in cx_Oracle query with the values provided

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

```
 cur.execute('select* form table where a = '?' and b = '?' and c = '?'', (val1,val2,val3))
```

I want to replace these placeholders with val1,2,3

Comment: what problems did you encounter?

Comment: A string starts at the quote mark and ends at the next corresponding quote mark so your string is `'select* form table where a = '` and then you have a `?` outside the string and start another string ... etc. If you are going to use bind variables `?` then don't surround them in quotes. If you want string values then use double quotes to start/end the python string and single quotes in the SQL statement for the SQL string literals. Also, you have a typo `from` not `form`.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle doesn't use '?' as placeholders for bind variables.  It uses colon-prefixed names like `:1` or `:empno`.

See [Using Bind Variables](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html) in the cx_Oracle Documentation. Also review the [examples](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples).

Try something like:

```
cur.execute('select * from table where a = :abv and b = :bbv and c = :cbv', [val1, val2, aval3])
```

or

```
cur.execute('select * from table where a = :abv and b = :bbv and c = :cbv', abv = val1, bbv = val2, cbv = val3])
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the end square bracket was a mistake in the second example?

Answer (score 1):

You do not state which SQL library you are using, but unless you are using something really exotic, you should omit the quotes around the placeholders:

```
cur.execute('select * from table where a = ? and b = ? and c = ?', (val1,val2,val3))
```

The SQL library will take the appropriate measures to get the values transferred to the DB engine!

Comment: Agreed that you shouldn't quote the `?`. However, "The SQL library will take care of quoting for you." No, any sane library will not add quotes but will pass the query directly to Oracle which will treat the `?` as bind variables and there is then no need to quote the variables being passed in.

Comment: @MT0 True; edited a bit. And I certainly hope that psycopg2 and sqlite don't send my data to Oracle! =)

Comment: The tags indicate it is Oracle, which isn't particularly exotic, but which doesn't use '?' for placeholders.